# Count the intersect between columns in a boolean data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for a more efficient way of finding:
count of different combinations of boolean values in rows of a dataframe.
returning the highest to lowest counts for the different column combinations.

code works but I'm hoping there is a more efficient way.

```
import pandas as pd

test_data={'a':[True,False,True,False,True,True,False],
          'b':[False,False,True,True,False,False,True],
          'c':[True,True,False,False,True,True,False],
          'd':[True,True,True,False,True,True,False]}

df=pd.DataFrame(test_data,columns=['a','b','c','d'])


columns_lst=df.columns.to_list()

df['check']=df.loc[:,['a','b','c','d']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.astype(int).astype(str)), axis=1)



result_check=df.check.value_counts().to_dict()


def get_cols(text_code):   
    result=[]
    for x,let in enumerate(text_code):
        if let=='1':
            result.append(columns_lst[x])
    return result



for key in result_check:
    result_check[key]={'cols':get_cols(key),'result':result_check[key]}
    
result_check=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result_check, orient='index')
result_check.sort_values(by='result',ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

`pandas.DataFrame.groupby()` would directly detect row duplicates. Here is what I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd

test_data={'a':[True,False,True,False,True,True,False],
           'b':[False,False,True,True,False,False,True],
           'c':[True,True,False,False,True,True,False],
           'd':[True,True,True,False,True,True,False]}

df=pd.DataFrame(test_data,columns=['a','b','c','d'])


df_count = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={0:'count'})

df_count_sorted = df_count.sort_values(by='count', ascending=False)
```

which gives:

```
       a      b      c      d  count
2   True  False   True   True      3
1  False   True  False  False      2
0  False  False   True   True      1
3   True   True  False   True      1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns were to increase. To view the result more clearly it would be good to combine just the columns where value = true to a name field.
perhaps:

```
import pandas as pd
test_data={'a':[True,False,True,False,True,True,False],
          'b':[False,False,True,True,False,False,True],
          'c':[True,True,False,False,True,True,False],
          'd':[True,True,True,False,True,True,False]}

df=pd.DataFrame(test_data,columns=['a','b','c','d'])

df_count=df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').to_frame() \
    .rename(columns={0:'combo'}) \
    .combo.value_counts()
```